# Group actions leaving the positive orthant invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions, convex-cone

Let $\Bbb R^n_{++} = \{x\in \Bbb R^n\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n> 0\}$ be the positive orthant.

**What are group actions which leaves $\Bbb R^n_{++}$ invariant?**

I think I have already found these ones:

- The group of permutation matrices $S_n$ and its subgroups.
- The group of diagonal matrices with positive diagonal elements.
- The group of component-wise powers, i.e. $\{x\mapsto (x_1^{\alpha},\ldots,x_n^{\alpha})\mid \alpha\in \Bbb R, \alpha \neq 0\}$ with the composition. Perhaps, this can be further extended to $\{x\mapsto (x_1^{\alpha_1},\ldots,x_n^{\alpha_n})\mid \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\neq 0 \}$.
- A combination of the above actions, e.g. $\{x\mapsto P\,(x_{1}^{\alpha},\ldots,x_n^{\alpha})\mid \alpha\in \Bbb R, \alpha \neq 0, P \in S_n\}$.

Is it all? Also, these actions are heavily using the fact that $\Bbb R^n_{++}$ is the interior of a polyhedral cone (the nonnegative orthant), I guess (hope) that there are actions which could be defined for general convex pointed cones in finite dimension.

Comment: This paper seems to deal with the same https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82734134.pdf

Comment: @baharampuri thank you very much, it indeed looks very interesting. However, at first glance (and if I understand it correctly), it seems to essentially deal with linear actions (so the first two bullet points in my examples but not with the third one).

Comment: I mean, literally any bijection from a set to itself is part of some group action.

Comment: @Surb You are right, that paper only deals with linear automorphisms. Unless you preserve some structures (say the automorphisms should be homeomorphisms) I think it will be too large, (= Bij(\mathbb{R}) )